# Suppress verbose info messages added by serilog

Tags: serilog

Perhaps this is a basic question, but I'm not finding an answer in the configuration documentation.  I'm using Serilog in several .NET Core APIs.  Serilog seems to add a log of informational messages reporting each and every API call in the format of:

`HTTP GET / responded 200 in [x] ms`

For my production code, I have my logging levels set to Warning and above.  And these messages added by Serilog seem to be a bit over the top for what I'd like in production.  It makes the logs a little difficult to sort through.

Does anybody know how I can configure it to not write to the log every time the API is hit?

Comment: You set the minimum log level to Warning, but you're still getting the Verbose events in your logs? I'm not understanding your situation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These are only logged [if you call `app.UseSerilogRequestLogging()`](https://github.com/serilog/serilog-aspnetcore/#request-logging) in your *Startup.cs* configuration. The simplest way to get rid of them is just to remove this line.